# A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_PUBLICATIONS_GETITEMSOFTYPE_83"

Tags: publishing, web8.5, database

I have been trying to publish a Dynamic Component Presentation but for some reason it keeps on failing with the following error:

[image]

When I preview the same component in the CMS getting below error:

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The wait
>   operation timed out

[image]

Comment: Can you run the *sp_updatestats* in CM database and then try again? also monitor is there any query running or taking longer to execute?

Comment: After running sp_updatestats in CM database publishing will work fine for one or two days after some days landing up again with same issue.

Comment: If that's the case, then you'll probably want to schedule this to run every 12 - 24 hours.

Comment: Are you up to date with hotfixes? You will find at least one hotfix relating to getitems SP's.

Comment: We didn't go with any hotfixes for DB issue, if any hotfixes are available related to the above error please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The components which were failing while publishing/previewing due to the database error was due to the Razor template which was taking more 90 to 200sec to execute that was causing the issue.

To resolve the above issue:

On the CMS and Publisher server went to the  Programs > SDL Web > SDL Web Content Manager configuration in the Microsoft Windows Start menu.

Navigate to the **Timeout** settings section

In that we increased the timeout value from 50sec to 900sec for the Seconds before a timeout error is generated when executing a query.

After increasing the timeout restarted COM+ and required services on both the server to ensure updated settings are used.

With the above changes publishing was going smooth but it was taking more time at rendering phase and apart from these few more observations are:

1. In the CMS DB when we checked the **CPU** usage was high sometimes it was reaching up to 99%.
2. In the Publisher server when checked the **Event Viewer** in the application and server logs -> navigate to tridion when we are publishing template issues related components getting "n" no of warnings.

After trying with multiple options we came to know that main culprit is "**Razor Template**".

In the razor template we are calling function called "**GetTemplateId("CPTest_CT")** which was causing the issue.

To resolve this issue as per time being wherever they are calling GetTemplateId passing the hardcoded id of component template. After doing this changes all the above issues got resolved.

I'm explaining in detail if next time anyone encounter this issue it may help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a typical timeout issue and there are a lot of similar question on this topic. The first thing to check is whether you have regular database maintenance performed? If not, do one (and start doing it on a **regular basis**, if possible daily) and try again. Database maintenance (Tridion specific) described [here](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/maintaining-sdl-tridion-databases).

You could increase the timeouts as described [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-43FE936B-56BF-468F-AA2C-340514B7776E&addHistory=true&query=timeout%2520settings&scope=&tid=815e6dc3-cf25-4a8c-8680-bd133352bee5&filename=GUID-43FE936B-56BF-468F-AA2C-340514B7776E.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-43FE936B-56BF-468F-AA2C-340514B7776E&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dtimeout%2520settings&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1549277403044&currentQuery=timeout%2520settings&currentScope=), but in most cases that is just masking the problem.

Similar questions:

- [SDL Tridion 2011 GUI Performance for large components](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/181/sdl-tridion-2011-gui-performance-for-large-components/182#182)
- [How to remove the transaction time out error?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5306/how-to-remove-the-transaction-time-out-error/5307#5307)
- [Unable to save Multimedia Component](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/unable-to-save-multimedia-component/4095#4095)
- [Timeout Expired for DecommissionPublicationTarget Tridion 8.5](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18816/timeout-expired-for-decommissionpublicationtarget-tridion-8-5)

Answer (score 1):

Timeout errors on a database pointing to lacking database maintenance, so first things I would recommend to look at is updating the database stats and rebuilding the indexes.

Always make sure you do regular database maintenance or its performance will deteriorate over time.

Ask your DBA team to schedule to run this **sp_updatestats** daily every 2hr or 3hr interval, Its'depends on your business how frequent CME used by the editor for content creation and editing.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_PUBLICATIONS_GETITEMSOFTYPE_83".
**You may have some poor template code, especially if publishing is generally slow.**

**Diagnose**

You can check this problem in the CMS Database

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT [ID]
  ,[SOURCE_ITEM_REFERENCE_ID]
  ,[SOURCE_ITEM_TYPE]
  ,[PUBLICATION_ID]
  ,[PUBLICATION_TARGET_ID]
  ,[TRUSTEE_ID]
  ,[PRIORITY]
  ,[PUBLISH_ACTION]
  ,[STATE]
  ,[STATE_CHANGE_TIME]
  ,[PUBLISH_TIME]
  ,[DEPLOY_TIME]
  ,[PUBLISHER_REQUEST]
  ,[INFORMATION]
  ,[IGNORE_RENDER_FAILURES]
  ,[MAX_RENDER_FAILURES]
  ,[SOURCE_ITEM_TITLE]
  ,[SOURCE_ITEM_PATH]
  ,[TARGET_TYPE_ID]
  ,[PUBLISHER_HOST]
  ,[CREATED_AT]
  ,[STARTED_AT]
  ,[FINISHED_AT]
  ,[RESOLVING_TIME]
  ,[RENDERING_TIME]
FROM [tridion_cm].[dbo].[PUBLISH_TRANSACTIONS]
Where STATE_CHANGE_TIME Between GetDate()-1 AND GetDate()
order by STATE_CHANGE_TIME desc
```

You will see that the Rendering time is NULL because it failed to render.

Set your SDL Console Timeouts to Stupid
[image: No Timeouts]

And restart your publisher

Then resubmit the failed publishing Tasks and check the rendering time when they are done.
[image: Carp Template Code]

Failed tasks will still be null but you will see the impact of poor template code by the **HUGE** rendering times.

**Resolution**

Rewrite the bad template code until you get more sensible rendering times, Then you can reset the SDL Console timeouts to better values.

Publishing will now be **so** much faster.